# how to port parfor loops on GPU?? how can i make use of NVIDIA GFORCE card 2GB inbuild in my laptop

Tags: matlab, gpu

```
 set(handles.txtOperation,'String','Creating NP List...');
pause(0.001);
NP_List = zeros([kv size(covtype2,2)-1]);
tic;
parfor count=1:kv
    index = find(idx == count);
    NP_List(count,:) = mean(covtype2(index,1:end-1));
end
toc;
```

how can i port this forloop on GPU i am having NVIDIA GFORCE with CUDA card 2gb in my laptop. how gpuArray would work in this code please help

Comment: Could you explain what you try to achieve using parfor? Your notebook probably has a single gpu, which means you can't run multiple gpu computations at the same time. Did you try using a gpuarray and a normal for loop?

Comment: Try using `arrayfun` with a `gpuarray` http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html?searchHighlight=arrayfun

Comment: no sir i have not tried. i am not getting how to approach GPU.
here in coding for loop calculating the mean of each cluster as a pseudopoint and saved it in the NP list. do i need to install additional Nvidia drivers for it. what settings should be done in matlab2010b to make use of Nvidia Gforce card